# How to horizontally flip labelled directions in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm augmenting data to learn from in tensorflow using the dataset API where augmentations are written as part of the graph. For my application I need to modify the labels as well as the images. The labels encode direction as:

```
0: up
1: right
2: down
3: left
```

For rotation augmentations I can do:

```
rotated_image = tf.image.rot90(image, 1)
rotated_label = (label + 1) % 4
```

I can horizontal flip the feature images using:

```
hflipped_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
```

but I can't figure out how to flip the labels left <-> right.

If the label is 1 it should become 3 and vice versa. 0 and 2 should remain unchanged. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flipped_label = tf.gather([0, 3, 2, 1], label)
```